# MatLab split character matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, char

I'm quite new to programming (MatLab) and I have a question.

I have a character matrix, consisting out of 500 rows and 81 columns. I would like 
to transform this matrix into a vector with 500 rows. Each row having 81 characters.

If i try the following:

```
for i = 1:length(CharMatrix)
    CharVect(i) = CharMatrix(i,:) 
end
```

it gives the error: `"Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch"`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you think the difference between a matrix and a vector is?

Comment: So, you want to be able to index an entire row of characters with only one index is that it? Why can't you use two as you're doing? What do you want to use this for? You might want to have a look at cells.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I have 500*81 characters. I want to transform these 500 rows with 81 characters to 500 double vectors, so i can use some calculations on them. If I have a single row of 81 characters, I can use the function [str2num(CharVector(:))]'.

Answer (score 0):

(given your clarifications), this might be the solution for you:

```
res = zeros(length(CharMatrix),1)
for i=1:length(CharMatrix)
    res(i) = str2num(CharMatrix(i,:))
end
```

no need to create CharVect explicitly.